# VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, enterprise-library, vsix

I tried to install enterprise library 6.0 recently in visual studio 2015 but the installer throws an error:

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

I couldn't resolve it.

```
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM - -------------------------------------------
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM - Initializing Install...
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM - Extension Details...
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Identifier         : A42E118F-C41F-47A2-ADB5-04CDEBF8EB90
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Name               : EnterpriseLibrary.Config.v6
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Author             : Microsoft
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Version            : 6.0.1304.1
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Description        : Launches the Microsoft Enterprise Library v6 Configuration Console
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  Locale             : en-US
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  MoreInfoURL        : 
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  InstalledByMSI     : False
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5]
19-Dec-16 9:59:48 AM - 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  SignatureState     : ValidSignature
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  Certificate Info   : 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      -------------------------------------------------------
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Serial Number] : 33000000B2E6906F8BE7453D5B0001000000B2
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Not Before]    : 25-Jan-13 4:03:41 AM
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Not After]     : 25-Apr-14 4:03:41 AM
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      [Thumbprint]    : E4EEC5DFB7F413E5A15191DA00D017F97E3A6260
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  Supported Products : 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -          Version : [11.0]
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -          Version : [11.0]
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -          Version : [11.0]
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  References         : 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      -------------------------------------------------------
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Name         : Visual Studio MPF
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Version      : [10.0,)
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      MoreInfoURL  : 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -      Nested       : No
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - Signature Details...
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM -  Extension is signed with a valid signature.
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - 
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - Searching for applicable products...
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - ssms
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Could anyone help me out ?

Comment: Related post - [Visual studio does not install .vsix files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25906944/465053)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the log file, we can get this extension is support on VS 2012 ultimate/premium/professional, and it found the installed product is VS 2015, so the error message “This extension is not installable on any currently installed products” popups, and we can also know this from system requirement of [Microsoft Enterprise Library 6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789).

To solve it, you can have a look at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309323/does-enterprise-library-6-work-with-visual-studio-2013-and-or-2015) and directly download the [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsole.V6.VS2015.vsix (Source)](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=9B6A6E6A51692041&resid=9B6A6E6A51692041%21129&authkey=ABDRbapYkYrj8uI) and use it to install, it works fine on my side.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the Supported Products section of the posted log file shows that the extension's supported version range for VS Ultimate/Premium/Pro is "[11.0]" means "only version 11.0". The range syntax is either a pair of low, high version numbers or a single version number, with square brackets meaning "inclusive" and parenthesis meaning "exclusive." The Visual Studio version numbers map to product names as follows: 10.0 is VS 2010, 11.0 is VS 2012, 12.0 is VS 2013, 14.0 is VS 2015, and 15.0 is VS 2017.

Comment: @SaraLiu I have downloaded `Votive2017.vsix` getting same error

Answer (score 8):

This VSIX is only designed to work with Visual Studio version 11 (Visual Studio 2012), as the error indicates - so you could use that version instead of VS 2015.

Here is the list of versions:

- VS 2019 Version 16
- VS 2017 Version 15
- VS 2015 Version 14
- VS 2013 Version 12
- VS 2012 Version 11

Comment: VS 2022 Version 17. Note that the 'ProductArchitecture' tag must probably be set to 'amd64', not 'x86', strangely. At least it is generated as such from the template for a new VSIX project and I'm not sure but I think I had only a successful install with 'amd64' even that my system has not a bit of AMD inside.

Answer (score 7):

On how to fix this, now with pictures:

1. [Download the wsix from here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicoVermeir.XAMLStyler)
2. <kbd>Right mouse</kbd> on the `XamlStyler.Package.vsix`
3. Open it with archiver (in my case it's 7zip, but you can use any other)
   [image]
4. <kbd>Right mouse</kbd> on the `extension.visxmanifest` -> Open
   [image]
5. Replace

   `<Installation InstalledByMsi="false" AllUsers="true">`
   `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />`
   `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />`
   `<InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,14.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />`
   `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />`
   `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />`
   `</Installation>`

With
    `<Installation InstalledByMsi="false" AllUsers="true">`
    `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />`
    `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />`
    `<InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />`
    `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />`
    `<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />`
    `</Installation>`

6. Don't forget to save and modify the archive.
7. Run `XamlStyler.Package.vsix` again and install VS extension.
8. Test if it works by <kbd>Right mouse</kbd>

[image]

I hope this will save you some time.

Answer (score 4):

In order to modify this Extension to allow Support for **Visual Studio 2015**, you would have to go into the '**Visual Studio Extension**' installer.

1. Open the **.vsix** file with any file archiver. (7-Zip for myself)
2. Locate the **.visxmanifest** file and Edit it.
3. Save the changes to the **.visxmanifest** file, exit and then run the **.vsix** VS Extension Installer file.

Note that for the Version Number in the Manifest an explicit Version is specified, which maps to a given version of Visual Studio. (eg: '**11.0**' corresponding to '**Visual Studio 2012**')

However, if you add a **comma** after the **Version Number**, this will allow you to set an explicit range for Version Support, or open Support for all Versions after a given Version.

Here are some examples below.

**(Allow only VS 2012)**

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
Version : [11.0]

**(Allow only VS 2012 & VS 2015)**

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
Version : [11.0,14.0]

**(Allow all VS Versions later than 2012)**
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
Version : [11.0,]

Here is Mads Kristensen's original [Blog Post](https://madskristensen.net/blog/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/) on forward porting Visual Studio Extensions from VS 2017 to VS 2019 for reference.

Comment: Don't we have to repack the extracted extension?

Answer (score 2):

You have it there:

```
Supported Products : 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
Version : [11.0]
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
Version : [11.0]
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
Version : [11.0]
```

Visual Studio 2015 is version 14.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check that `This VSIX is installed by Windows Installer` option is checked in manifest file of Visual Studio(VS) extension. You'll find this option under `Install Targets` tab while viewing the `*.vsixmanifest` file of the VS extension you're creating:

[image]