# Problem with installing Visual Studio extensions, This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and I seem to have a problem with installing extensions.

I tried installing the Visual Studio Live Share extension from [This link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsls-vs) and followed the instructions.

When I tried running the file downloaded from this link I got [This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1U4.png)

The following is the log it provided me

```
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - -------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - 15.0.403+g26ad50685f
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - -------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - Command line parameters:
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\user\Downloads\Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.vsix
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - -------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
28/11/2018 14:42:43 - -------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:44 - Initializing Install...
28/11/2018 14:42:44 - Extension Details...
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Identifier         : Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Name               : VS Live Share - Preview
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Author             : Microsoft
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Version            : 0.3.953.0
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Description        : Real-time collaborative development  from the comfort of your favorite tools.
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   Locale             : en-US
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
28/11/2018 14:42:44 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
28/11/2018 14:42:44 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   SignatureState     : ValidSignature
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   Certificate Info   : 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       -------------------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Serial Number] : 330000026ECE6AE5984BFC96A900000000026E
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Not Before]    : 07/09/2018 00:00:30
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Not After]     : 07/09/2019 00:00:30
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       [Thumbprint]    : 99B6246883B4B32EA59AE18B36945D205A876800
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   Supported Products : 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -           Version : [15.0.27220,)
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   References         : 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   Prerequisites      : 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       -------------------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Name         : Visual Studio core editor
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Version      : [15.0,)
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       -------------------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Name         : JavaScript and TypeScript language support
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Version      : [15.0,)
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       -------------------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Name         : C# and Visual Basic
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Version      : [15.0,)
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       -------------------------------------------------------
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Name         : Just-In-Time debugger
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -       Version      : [15.0,)
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - Signature Details...
28/11/2018 14:42:46 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - 
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - Searching for applicable products...
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - Found installed product - Global Location
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
28/11/2018 14:42:46 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at-  VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable\`1& skuData)
   at-  VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at-  VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at-  System.Threading.Tasks.Task\`1.InnerInvoke()
   at-  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I also tried installing the Doxygen extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=satishc.vsts-ext-code-doc-with-doxygen) but got the same error and pretty much the same log.

Any idea on what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/521

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Related post - [VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41215916/465053)

Answer (score 0):

15.0.403 is a very old version of vsixinstaller. With the latest VS 2017 updates it should be 15.9.3032.

Try to search your system disk for a newer vsixinstaller.exe version.

Answer (score 0):

> problem with installing Visual Studio extensions, This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

When we install some extension, we need to know some information about this extension.

For the Visual Studio Live Share extension, there is a **Installation** on the homepage:

[image]

Which need the **Visual Studio 2017 15.6** or higher.

For the extension Doxygen, this is a **Visual Studio Team Services extension** not for Visual Studio, and it also have some Pre-requisites:

[image]

Hope this helps.