# Can't install the extension on Visual Studio 2017 after installing Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

Only Visual Studio 2019 is present in VSIXInstaller, Visual Studio 2017 is missing and when I want to install the extension specifically for Visual Studio 2017 I can't do that

Comment: Which extension?  Are you sure that version of the extension is also compatible with VS2017?

Comment: This extension is "Altimesh Hybridizer Essentials"

Comment: But this applies not only to it, after installing VS 2019 I lost the ability to install any extension on VS 2017.

Comment: You might try to use command prompt to launch `%ProgramFilesx86%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<whatever>\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe` to install the extension via command line.

Comment: I thought about that too. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work, only VS 2019 on the list.I looked at the logs that vsixinstaller writes, and when searching for products, he just does not see VS 2017 although it is installed.

Log:
`
14.04.2019 6:23:54 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
14.04.2019 6:23:54 - 15.9.3039
14.04.2019 6:23:56 - Searching for applicable products...
14.04.2019 6:23:56 - Found installed product - Global Location
14.04.2019 6:23:56 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Enterprise 2019`

Comment: On their VS marketplace page, it says "Installing Visual Studio 2019 preview breaks our installer. Visual studio 2019 support is planned for Q1 2019".  From the phrasing it's not clear if VS2019 breaks the installer on other versions, but it might be worth contacting them to find out more.

Comment: Have you installed the extension in VS2019? I tried to install the extension in my machine with VS2015,2017 and VS2019, but it works well. The extension can be installed well in VS2017. Pic like [this](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/v-lali_microsoft_com/EZ_riegs0UNDlYrjB2aFCDIB1d2GFhcmMxnnBFybttQLbw?e=SqX8Kp). Try update the vs2017 to latest version and reinstall the extension to check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue crops up due to the '**Visual Studio Extension File**' not having the appropriate supported VS Version Numbers specified in the '**.vsixmanifest**'.

(Changing the supported Version Number range will allow support for previous or future versions of Visual Studio.)

Here is a [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005745/3250774) to an answer of mine which covers the issue and resolution. (Which has a worked example of allowing VS 2015 where only VS 2012 was supported)